# I'm used everyday and needed until I'm fed - Then you'll be dead. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I'm light
>
> I'm bright
>
> I'm hot
>
> I help at night
>
> I'm useful for this, I'm useful for that
>
> But feed me what I like and I'd get greedier
>
> And greedier
>
> Until There's nothing left
>
> You can consider it theft
>
> Come close to me and I'll harm you
>
> I might even kill you
>
> But my weakness is what you consider essential
>
> But you can only defeat me if you're confidential
>
> I need what your lungs need
>
> For I love to feed
>
> But when I'm out, I suffer defeat.
>
> But the harmed ones will be as cooked meat.

**Who am I?**

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the downvote please? I worked hard on making this rhyme xD

Comment: Maybe because it was way too easy? But easy puzzles are welcome here as much as some people may not like them. See http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3015/is-it-ok-to-post-simple-puzzles/3017#3017

Comment: Not that I consider myself an expert in making riddles (because I'm not), but maybe you can include vague hints instead of direct ones. So instead hinting to the answer, hint to a hint that hints the answer.

Comment: I agree with the above commenters: many of the clues in this riddle aren't cryptic enough. "Light", "bright", "hot" all point towards fire, and "cooked meat" just confirms it. **A good riddle should include misdirection**, often making you think the solution might be one thing when really it's something else (though of course you need to include enough clues to ensure that that first thing wouldn't *also* work as an answer). For an example of a riddle with a big red herring, see [this one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12857/you-dirty-mind-what-am-i).

Comment: I'd say remove the first 4 lines and the last, then it'd be a little less obvious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer:

> Fire (or a torch)

I'm light

> Fire produces light.

I'm bright

> Fire produces a bright light.

I'm hot

> Duh!. It's hot.

I help at night

I'm useful for this, I'm useful for that

> People used to use torches or any kind of fire to help in the darkness.

But feed me what I like and I'd get greedier

> Fire requires fuel.

And greedier

> More and more fuel.

Until There's nothing left

You can consider it theft

> It will burn almost everything you throw at it.

Come close to me and I'll harm you

> Who hasn't got burned (literally) at least once

I might even kill you

> Obviously you can die from fire if you are not [one of the fantastic 4](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0004551/?ref_=tt_cl_t3).

But my weakness is what you consider essential

> You can stop fire with water.

But you can only defeat me if you're confidential

> I don't really understand this one.

I need what your lungs need

> Fire needs oxygen to burn.

For I love to feed

But when I'm out, I suffer defeat.

> In vacuum the fire gets extinguished.

But the harmed ones will be as cooked meat.

> Hmmm...grilled pork, yum yum.

Comment: Come on, I thought this would be hard >:(

Comment: @AbAppletic, sorry is not that hard. by reading the firsts lines i get the idea of fire and then it matches the resto of lines ..

Comment: @AbAppletic. Yep...it was easy. I added the answer after reading the first 5 lines. Then I read the others while writing the reasoning.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have included those lines :P

Comment: It wasn't really hard though :P I got it in like 3 seconds :)

Comment: Fire, air, water, time, etc are all common answers one considers to riddles. If you're going to make a riddle on one of these, you need to be extremely careful in disguising it as something else. (In particular, light, bright, and hot are attributes which all point immediately to fire!)