# Let's keep this civilized

Tags: riddle, visual

The images below are connected by a single word:

[image: A Knight in shining armour with shield and lance]

[image: The Silhouette of a Cat]

[image: A bar of gold]

[image: A golf club]

[image: Fire]

[image: A fair ground]

What is the word, and what are the connections?

Comment: If you were Japanese or Chinese, you could play this sort of thing with the ideograph characters rather than pictures; and in fact they have such puzzles in those cultures (commonly appearing in newspapers and magazines).

Comment: E.g. take a crack at this one: http://enbanrider.com/RPG/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/002_wadoukaichin.jpg

Comment: @kaz its all Greek to me I'm afraid.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think it is

> Fight

- Knight

> Fight Night

- Cat

> Cat Fight

- Gold

> Bar fight (Thanks @Gustavo Gabriel)

- Club

> Fight Club

- Fire

> Firefight

- Fair

> Fair Fight

Comment: Gold bar = Bar fight

Comment: Well done.  You got it. +1

Answer (score 7):

Could it be

> BLACK?

- Knight

  > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhRUe-gz690
- Cat

  > Black cats are famously (un)lucky.
- Gold

  > [Black gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_gold) - oil, a source of wealth for many countries.
- Club

  > Clubs are black when you play cards.
- Fire

  > The [Blackfyres](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Blackfyre).
- Fair

  > Not sure about this one.

Comment: This was my first impression as well, but I couldn't get it to fit the last two (or the title, beyond some vague "civil rights" link).

Comment: @F1Krazy My first thought from the title was that it might be one of those "[riddles for dirty minds](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/12857/5373)", the second image being "pussy".

Comment: Really not bad.  I was worried I'd made this too broad until I got to the last couple. +1

Comment: @Brent Having seen the accepted answer, I do agree that it fits better.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is

> Fortune

This is my explainations

> A soldier of *fortune* is an adventurer or a mercenary 
>  Black cat either means bad or good *fortune* depending on the local folklore 
>  "Of *fortune* and gold" is a movie 
>  There is a golf course at *fortune* bay 
>  "Fire and *fortune*" is a song by Josienne Clarke & Ben Walker 
>  Theme park: tickets of *fortune* is a video slot machine

Comment: Not bad.  these explanations are reaching a little further than you'd need to with the 'correct' answer.  +1 though

Comment: Yeah, I feel like I found only half the matches and then searched on Google for possibilities to fill the rest. The funniest one is that I came up with gold is fortune because of the french meaning of fortune

Comment: @BrentHackers the answer is correct and only the explanations are wrong?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel  No.  The answer is not correct.  Sorry, I really didn't make that clear, did I?

Comment: @BrentHackers No problem, just asking to see if I can keep looking for the answer or if I should improve the explanations :)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative i thought of, fitting for a good number of them:

> Fish

Knight

> Spearfish

Cat

> Catfish

Gold

> Goldfish

Club

> Fishstick

Fire

> Fish.. roasted by fire? Firefish? [Crimsonfish](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Crimsonfish)? (This is when it all falls apart)

Carnival

> Clownfish (a stretch, i know)

Comment: I'd say it fell apart at club mate ha ha. Even if I recognised 'fishstick' as a real word (don't tempts me to add a UK tag), using a golf club to represent a stick would be a stretch for me.  Some good fits though, really. +1  (And at least a firefish is an actual real world thing, if not common knowledge)